# if condition executing differently

Tags: javascript, html

I have different functions which return true or false but I dont get how `false==false==true` is a true condition? I think it should alert `b` but instead it alerts `a`.

```js
function myFunctions() {
  if (false == false == true) {
    alert("a")
  } else {
    alert("b")
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunctions()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: Op. precedence will be from left to right. when `false==false` that is true & it is equal to `true`

Comment: It read this function like this `function myFunctions(){
    if(false==(false==true)){
      alert("a")
    } else {
      alert("b")
    }
}`

Comment: @SuperUser, no, that's incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

You can only compare two boolean values at a time. Your example will start evaluating from the left to the right, so essentially it is:

```
(false == false) == true   // which is true
```

Here's a reference for [operator precendence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) in Javascript, which determines the order of evaluation of the specific operator.

Answer (score 4):

Try this, `false==false` which is `true` only and substitute `true` in `(false==false)` and `true==true` also true only

```js
function myFunctions() {
  alert(false); //returns false
  alert(false == false); //returns (false==false) i.e true
  alert(false == false == false); // (false==false) = true and substitue true in (false==false) then (true==false) which returns false
  alert(false == false == true); // true==true
  if (false == false == true) {
    alert("a")
  } else {
    alert("b")
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunctions()">Try it</button>
```